# Dynamic MaxLength in model MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I have situation where the max length of customer name is depends on business roles.

So normal way is

```
public class Customer { 
[DisplayName("Name")]
[Required]
[MaxLength(20)]
public string customer_name{ get; set; }}
```

As you see, I set max length is 20 for customer name. Can change the max length in runtime based on business roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not utilizing the attribute, no. You'll have to do custom validation. At the simplest level you can just do something like the following in your action:

```
if (model.role == "Foo" && model.customer_name.Length > 20)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("customer_name", "Name must be less than or equal to 20 characters");
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
```

Then, you would simply remove the `MaxLength` data annotation.

However, this particular data annotation controls more than just validation; it also effects the length of the column in the database (which is another reason you can't change it on the fly). So, if you want a limit at the database level, you'll have to leave it and simply set it to the maximum value that any of the various roles could have. Then, you can implement custom validation on top of that to limit it to less in cases where that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this in the View, just add the length to the model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = @Model.MaxLength } })
```

Technically this only restricts the number of characters the user can type into a textbox, but you could add additional validation server side if required.